# How does RequestContext.reject work?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

Looking at spray API the [`RequestContext`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.routing.RequestContext) is immutable and `RequestContext.reject` returns `Unit` - so how does the Spray routes know that the "request" was rejected?

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/routes/

I.e.: lets say we have routes: a->b

If `b` rejects the request (by calling `RequestContext.reject`) how is `a` notified of it?

I guess I am not sure what documentation means by "responder" (see [The Responder Chain](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/#the-responder-chain) in the docs) of `RequestContext`. Would the responder for `b` be `a`? Or is the responder the original `Actor` who initiated the http-request?

Comment: Where did the other answer go? I think it provided a few complementary links like the one to the "Responder Chain" explanation that I found helpful as well.

Comment: @jrudolph I deleted it after seeing your more complete answer as I was mostly just making educated guesses. I undeleted it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How it works is this:

1. The spray-can layer HTTP connection actor sends an HttpRequest object to the service and expects an HttpResponse for it
2. HttpService receives this messages and saves the original sender (i.e. the spray-can layer connection actor) as the root "responder"
3. It creates the [RequestContext](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/RequestContext.scala) which holds both the request and the responder as the ActorRef to which responses need to be sent to.
4. Basic operations on the RequestContext like [`complete`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/RequestContext.scala#L228) just send a message to the responder to complete the request
5. Also, for `reject` a message is sent to the responder. However, as the original responder is just an ActorRef of the spray-can level Actor and the Rejection message isn't handled by spray-can, the routing layer has to hook into the message processing to use the RejectionHandler to convert a rejection to an ordinary HttpResponse. This can be done e.g. by using `RequestContext.withRouteResponseMapped` which returns a **new RequestContext** which contains a new responder that wraps the old one appling some function onto all messages received by this responder before forwarding the result to the original responder.
6. This way `RequestContext.withRejectionHandling` can be implemented: it returns a **new RequestContext** which contains a new wrapped responder that applies the given function to Rejection messages before forwarding the result to the wrapped responder.
7. Now, how does your example of `a ~ b` work (I understand that's what you meant by "a->b")? If you look at the [implementation of `~`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/RouteConcatenation.scala), it just uses `withRejectionHandling`:

.

```
def ~(otherRoute: Route): Route = { ctx ⇒
  firstRoute {
    ctx.withRejectionHandling { rejections ⇒
      otherRoute(ctx.withRejectionsMapped(rejections ++ _))
    }
  }
}
```

It passes to the first route (`a`) a RequestContext that has a Rejection handler registered that will run the second route (`b`) if the first one is rejected. The second route will then be called with another RequestContext that is also derived from the original one that in case of another rejection will aggregate the rejections from both routes.

You can also see what's happening by looking at a stack trace. For these route definitions

```
val a = (ctx: RequestContext) => ctx.reject()
val b = { (ctx: RequestContext) =>
  Thread.dumpStack()
  ctx.complete("hello world")
}
val demoRoute =  a ~ b
```

This stack trace is printed (needs to be read from the bottom up):

```
  java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)

    // arrived at `b`
    at spray.examples.DemoService$$anonfun$3.apply(DemoService.scala:42)
    at spray.examples.DemoService$$anonfun$3.apply(DemoService.scala:41)

    // `~` running the second route
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:32)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:31)

    // `RequestContext.withRejectionHandling` handling the Rejection
    at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anonfun$withRejectionHandling$1.applyOrElse(RequestContext.scala:130)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)

    // `RequestContext.withRouteResponseHandling` doing its thing
    at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$1.handle(RequestContext.scala:84)
    at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
    at spray.routing.RequestContext.reject(RequestContext.scala:202)

    // `a` rejecting the request
    at spray.examples.DemoService$$anonfun$2.apply(DemoService.scala:40)
    at spray.examples.DemoService$$anonfun$2.apply(DemoService.scala:40)

    // `~` running route `a`
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:29)

    // HttpService infrastructure
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:35)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:33)
    at spray.routing.HttpServiceBase$class.runSealedRoute$1(HttpService.scala:36)
    at spray.routing.HttpServiceBase$$anonfun$runRoute$1.applyOrElse(HttpService.scala:46)

    // HttpService receiving the request
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

As a side note: most of the complexity comes from spray completing responses by side-effects i.e. by sending a message to an ActorRef. In the upcoming successor of spray, akka-http, a [Route will simply return a RouteResult](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/server/package.scala#L11), instead, which makes the control flow easier to understand. E.g. compare the new implementation of [`Route.~`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/server/RouteConcatenation.scala) which now just pattern matches on the result of the first route to see if it rejected the request in which case the second route is run.

Comment: Wow, this is a rather epic explanation of how routing works. The breakdown of the stack trace would be really good information in a non-reference section of Akka HTTP docs.

Answer (score 2):

While [`RequestContext`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.routing.RequestContext) itself may be immutable, it contains values which clearly indicate that it performs side effects. Without looking at the code, I would imagine it has something to do with the `responder: ActorRef` value. It's probably not hard to find the implementation of `reject` on github.

```
case class RequestContext(
  request: HttpRequest, 
  responder: ActorRef, 
  unmatchedPath: Path) extends Product with Serializable
```

Edit: calls to `reject` do send a message to `responder` (via comment by @j-keck) https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/1ce512cbd17380655fe1756b524c7f19dc9a3de3/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/RequestContext.scala#L195

Edit: I just noticed the last part of your question. Based what I see in the code, it's possible that the responder has been replaced in some custom directive. I have no idea if this actually happens in practice, sorry. Based on the directives documentation, the original `responder` should eventually receive the response, perhaps indirectly. My guess is that the original request is closed when a `Future` created by a call to `?` is completed. This call to `?` will eventually time out if no response is sent to the `responder` in the original `RequestContext`.

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/#the-responder-chain

> The responder of the original RequestContext, which is the sender
>   ActorRef of the HttpRequest, receives the response and sends it out to
>   the client.

Comment: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/1ce512cbd17380655fe1756b524c7f19dc9a3de3/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/RequestContext.scala#L195